# Index 736 out of bounds for length 500

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to read some csv files and construct a graph but keep getting this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Index 736 out of bounds for length 500
at CitiesClass.main(CitiesClass.java:35)
```

which is apparently this line

```
[Integer.parseInt(results[1])]=1.0;
```

but what exactly am I doing wrong?

Full code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class CitiesClass {

 static int N = 500;
 static double [][] edges = new double[N][N];
 static TreeMap <Integer,String> cityNames = new TreeMap
    <Integer,String>();
 static ArrayList<String> convert(ArrayList<Integer> m) {
    ArrayList<String> z = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Integer i:m) z.add(cityNames.get(i));
    return z;
   }

 static HashSet<ArrayList<String>> convert
  (HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> paths) {
    HashSet <ArrayList <String>> k = new HashSet <ArrayList<String>>();
    for (ArrayList <Integer> p:paths) k.add(convert(p));
    return k;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
  edges[i][j]=0.0;
  Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("randomGraph.csv"));
  String z = s.nextLine();
  while (s.hasNext()) {
    z =s.nextLine();
    String[] results = z.split(",");
    edges[Integer.parseInt(results[0])]
    [Integer.parseInt(results[1])]=1.0;
    edges[Integer.parseInt(results[1])]
    [Integer.parseInt(results[0])]=1.0;
  }

  s = new Scanner(new FileReader("cities.csv"));
  z =s.nextLine();
  while (s.hasNext()) {
    z =s.nextLine();
    String[] results = z.split(",");
    cityNames.put(Integer.parseInt(results[0]), results[1]);
  }

  graph G = new graph(edges);
  int st = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  int fin = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  System.out.println("Shortest path from " + cityNames.get(st)
      + " to " + cityNames.get(fin) + " is" + 
      convert(G.shortestPaths(st,fin)));
  }
}
```

Comment: the exception message plus `int N = 500` _seem_ related.

Comment: @luk2302 I see, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

> but what exactly am I doing wrong?

You are assuming that `0 <= Integer.parseInt(results[1]) < 500`. Clearly, you are reading a graph with at least 736 nodes (or 737, if the indices of the graph are zero-based).

I might look to see if the first line of `randomGraph` (the one you discard) contains the size of the graph.

```
String z = s.nextLine();
```

Try parsing that:

```
int graphSize = Integer.parseInt(z);
```

and then allocating your matrix based on that:

```
edges = new double[graphSize][graphSize]
```

Comment: This produces an error:  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4,752,45.97182"`

Comment: OK, well, that looks like it's got more data there than just the number of nodes. The 752 looks relevant; no idea what the 4 and the 45. blah are. So, split it (like you are doing) and parse the relevant part.

Comment: I believe the string above is the first line in the file and 736 is in the 2nd. Still no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Yes: the 752 is in the first line. Extract that *somehow*, use it to initialize your array. Then, when you parse the 736 in the second (or any subsequent) line, your array is sufficiently large.